# Why is the return value type of std::round not an integer?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, rounding

I had/have some confusion regarding rounding a `float`/`double` variable to the nearest integer. While googling, I came across [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) cppreference page for rounding. On that page, it says:

```
float       round ( float arg );         // (1)
float       roundf( float arg );         // (2)
double      round ( double arg );        // (3)
long double round ( long double arg );   // (4)
double      round ( IntegralType arg );  // (5)
```

Here, I don't understand why is the return value type `float`, `double`, or `long double`? For example, if I have a variable `float x` and `2.5 <= x < 3.5` then its rounded value is `3`. That can be represented using just an `int`, right? So, **why is the return value type of `std::round` not an `int` (or `long it` for `long double`)?**

---

On that page, it also says:

> 1-5) Computes the nearest integer value to arg (in floating-point format), rounding halfway cases away from zero, regardless of the current rounding mode.

So, what does exactly *"integer value to arg (in floating-point format)"* mean?

---

To understand this `std::round`, I did one small experiment:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    float var               = 3.14;
    int   rounded_var_int   = std::round(var);
    float rounded_var_float = std::round(var);

    std::cout << rounded_var_int << ", " << rounded_var_float << std::endl;  // 3, 3
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, this made me even more confused because everything ran just fine.

So, the last question:
In the above code, `int rounded_var_int = std::round(var)` is just fine or do I need to explicitly cast it to `int` e.g. `int rounded_var_int = static_cast<int>(std::round(var))` to avoid any potential bug(s)?

Comment: You have [`std::roundl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) for that (or maybe `std::roundll`).

Comment: You can't store `10^200` in the built in integer types

Comment: For your 2'nd question: You're fine. The value just gets truncated.

Comment: @SolvedGames Might floating point errors creep in if the result of `std::round` is large enough and give you 1 less than you're expecting when you truncate to an `int`?

Comment: *to avoid any potential bug(s)* -- You're putting a lot of faith in floating-point functions giving you your desired result 100% of the time, unless you can live with those values that just "don't seem to behave".

Comment: If you have a floating point value, and you want to round it, and the value is guaranteed to fit in an integer type, and you will be using the result as an integer, then yes, it would be convenient for `round` functions to return an integer type. But that is not the general use case, and converting the result to an integer type is an extra cost you don't always want to pay for (specially if you intend to cast back to a floating type).  If you want to do that, you can simply cast to an integer type to truncate, or do the same with your value `+ 0.5` to round, or cast the result of `std::round`.

Answer (score 5):

> Why is the return value type of std::round not an integer?

Because the representable range of floating point types generally exceed the range of fundamental integer types and thus those integer types cannot represent all potential return values.

Besides finite rounded values that exceed the range of integer types, other problematic values are infinities, not-a-number values, negative zero which are returned without change.

> rounded value is 3. That can be represented using just an int, right?

**This** value can be represented using `int`. But being able to represent one, or some of the values isn't sufficient. The return type should be able to represent **all** rounded values. And that isn't generally achievable with `int`.

> In the above code, `int rounded_var_int = std::round(var)` is just fine or do I need to explicitly cast it to int e.g. `int rounded_var_int = static_cast<int>(std::round(var))` to avoid any potential bug(s)?

Floating point types are implicitly convertible to integer types. The result of the implicit conversion is the same as the result of the static cast.

It is a narrowing conversion. Neither implicit nor explicit conversion is safe in the sense that if the floating point value is outside of representable range, then the behaviour of the program is undefined. Both conversions are safe in the sense that if the value is representable, then the value will remain unchanged by the conversion.